# GraphQL query orderBy number including null

Tags: craft3, entries, ordering, graphql

I am attempting to query entries via that have a field (ex `numberField`)  with field type Number. Some of the entries don't have a value for this field, so in the response it has `null`. I am wanting to order the entries by this Number field, but I am wanting the ones with a valid number to be ordered first, and then the ones with values of `null` to come after. Examples below:

**Rough query**

```
query getElements {
  entries(
    section: ["anEntryType"]
    orderBy: "numberField ASC"
  ) {
    id
    ... on anEntryType_default_Entry {
      numberField
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "numberField": null
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "numberField": null
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "numberField": 100
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "numberField": 200
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired Response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "numberField": 100
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "numberField": 200
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "numberField": null
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "numberField": null
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
query getElements {
  entries(
    section: ["anEntryType"]
    orderBy: [
      {
        field: "numberField"
        direction: "ASC"
      },
      {
        field: "numberField"
        direction: "ASC"
        value: null
      }
    ]
  ) {
    id
    ... on anEntryType_default_Entry {
      numberField
    }
  }
}
```

or

To sort the entries with a valid numberField value first, followed by the entries with a null value for numberField, you can use the following orderBy parameter in your query:

```
orderBy: [{
  field: "numberField",
  direction: "ASC",
  custom: "IS NOT NULL"
}, {
  field: "numberField",
  direction: "ASC"
}]
```

The custom parameter allows you to specify a custom sorting function that is applied after the initial sorting based on the field and direction parameters. The value "IS NOT NULL" tells Craft CMS to sort the entries with a non-null value for numberField before the entries with a null value for numberField.

Here is an example of how your GraphQL query would look with this sorting function included:

```
query getElements {
  entries(
    section: ["anEntryType"],
    orderBy: [{
      field: "numberField",
      direction: "ASC",
      custom: "IS NOT NULL"
    }, {
      field: "numberField",
      direction: "ASC"
    }]
  ) {
    id
    ... on anEntryType_default_Entry {
      numberField
    }
  }
}
```